# Правильно ли реализованы связи в моделе django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Всем доброго времени. Подскажите не намудрил ли я с созданием связей в моделе. Нужно реализовать дневник, пользователь сам создает название дневника, в нем он создает категории и уже в категориях создает заметки. Ну в общем сама модель ниже:

```
class DiaryCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='Новый дневник', max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название дневника')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор дневника')
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата обновления')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Дневник'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Дневники'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class DiarySubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='Новая категория дневника', max_length=150, db_index=True,
                            verbose_name='Название категории')
    category_main = models.ForeignKey(DiaryCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор катгории')
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата обновления категрии')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория дневника'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории дневника'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class DiaryNote(models.Model):
    category_main = models.ForeignKey(DiaryCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Дневник')
    category_sub = models.ForeignKey(DiarySubCategory, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория дневника')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, default='Новая заметка', verbose_name='Заметка')
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Текст заметки')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата обновления')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заметка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заметки'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Подкатегория точно нужна? И связь FK Заметки и Категории не нужна в таком случае. Категорию можно через Подкатегрию получать.

Comment: Да подкатегория нужна. Возможно так же лишним будет указывать связь автора категории и подкатегории? Правильно ли ход мыли, что если указан автор самой главной категории, то ниже по иерархии не нужно эту связь указывать, а узнать автора можно будет по цепочке заметка-подкатегория-дневник?

Comment: Да, верно... `DiaryNote.category_sub.category_main.author`